# Excel documents failed to open in client

Tags: 2013, excel, office-web-apps

One user tried opening MS Office excel document which has macros in it, due to web app restriction he was able only to open document in client.
While opening, excel notified him as standard ribbon notification, that there are macros in document, he clicked and enabled them and tried to edit excel document, but he got very generic error message.
[image]

I tried many things, restarting his PC, clearing browser cache, Office Upload center cache, checking if document was locked on server. None above helped and he is still unable to open excel document in client.
He can use document in web app mode, but with no macros and other advanced features that are unavailable in web app.
He is unable to use any excel document that has macros, but can open and edit excel documents in client that don't have macros.

I looked [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/excel-2016-were-having-trouble-connecting-to-the/8c28bd66-c678-403b-a527-d6ce46bbebf4) and followed suggestions, but nothing helped.
Do you have any suggestion how to overcome this error?